# PdfSharp and iText7

Tags: itext7, pdfsharp

I am replacing PdfSharp with iText7 and I am not sure why when I use the same x and y coordinates I am getting different results. I am using `735` and `520` on both but they are printing on different location on the pdf file. Any help with this would be great. PdfSharp is using a `double` and iText7 is using `float` but they are exactly the same, under the hood.

the origin (0, 0) is top left and coordinates grow right and down. The unit of measure is always point (1/72 inch).
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics.ashx

PdfSharp

```
 PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics gfx = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
 dfSharp.Drawing.Layout.XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
 pnt = new XPoint(735, 520);
 gfx.DrawString("Text Enter", font, XBrushes.White, pnt);
```

iText7

```
  iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rectangle = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(735, 520, 100, 100);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, rectangle);
  Style normal = new Style();
  PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
                            normal.SetFont(font).SetFontSize(34).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);


  Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
  .Add(_versionNumber)
  .SetFontSize(34)
  .SetFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE)
  .SetFont(font);
```

Comment: Maybe they are using different coordinate systems. iText usually uses PDF user space coordinates which typically have their origin in the lower left of the page. Does PdfSharp use the same coordinate system? (By the way, your iText code is unnecessarily complex if all you want to do is drawing a single text piece somewhere on the page...)

Comment: from pdfsharp wiki The origin (0, 0) is top left and coordinates grow right and down. The unit of measure is always point (1/72 inch). I would think that is the same as iText

Comment: *"The origin (0, 0) is top left and coordinates grow right and down. The unit of measure is always point (1/72 inch). I would think that is the same as iText"* -  No, definitively it's not the same. See my previous comment. Apparently PdfSharp has defined its own coordinate system. The default PDF user space coordinates grow right and ***up***, and the origin can be *anywhere* but usually is in the ***bottom*** left.

Comment: what are you using to get the coordinates I tried gimp .

Comment: What do you mean by "get the coordinates"? You do have coordinates in one coordinate system, so how about *calculating* the coordinates in the other from it? Simply read the top user space **y** coordinate of the page you're processing (``pdfPage.GetCropBox().getTop()`) and subtract the PdfSharp **y** coordinate from it. Beware, though, there might also be other differences; in particular rectangles in iText are determined by the coordinates of the lower left corner and width and height. Maybe PdfSharp uses the upper left corner there...

Comment: @mkl would I do the same process to get the  x coordinate?

Comment: *"would I do the same process to get the x coordinate?"* - Not exactly, here you don't subtract but add something, you take the user space **x** coordinate of the left page border (`pdfPage.GetCropBox().GetLeft()`) and add the PdfSharp **x** coordinate to it. But you'll see that  user space **x** coordinate of the left page border often is 0, so more often than not you don't need to change the **x** coordinate at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paragraph.SetFixedPosition(0, 800, 200) will put you at the Top left edge of the page, 200 is the width.  Itext7 PDF coordinates start at the bottom left. (0,0) is the bottom left corner of the document normally.